# Calling functions from loop reading arguments from file

Tags: function, shell, argument-passing

I'm trying to call a function multiple times by calling it in a loop. The arguments for the function are in a file.

```
while IFS=: read arg1 arg2
do 
func $arg1 $arg2
done < file
```

The arguments are stored in the file as

```
file1arg1 file2arg2
file2arg2 file2arg2...
```

Can anyone help what am I foing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefining `$IFS` changes what `read` splits by. Stop doing that.